# AngularJS: How to make field read only inside directive

Tags: html, angularjs

For my website I have a custom directive for some fields, I would like to dynamically change in the directive whether a particular field should be read only or not based on some values.

Is this possible? and if so how?

Comment: what about [ngReadonly](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think a directive is necessary for what you want to do as `ng-readonly` can take arguments, you would use it like this;

```
<input type="search" ng-readonly"variable===true"/>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your custom directive can be used as class i.e,restrict :'C',then

```
ng-class="{className:[condition]}"

ng-class="{custom-directive:[value =='ABC']}"
```